# Use Threads for image analysis and microcontroller actuation or not

Tags: multithreading, image-processing, robotics

One question please.
I have a program that makes analysis of an image coming from a camera (with opencv). It has to take the values from that analysis (at a specific "sampling time") and send it to a microcontroller. The analysis part cant stop making analysis because it will let the system "blind" (thats what we think). So...I have read that to pass values from one file to another, if "return" is used, the program stops that file, so one has to use threads...Is this the best way to adress this problem?. Or is there another way to do it in just one thread??

(The overall idea is to control a machine that uses motors with the analysis from a camera, the question is, should this be done with threads or linearly.)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What machine and operating system is your program running on? What language is it? How is it connected to the microcontroller? What is the microcontroller? What volume of data do you need to send? How often?

Comment: @MarkSetchell
Thanks for your answer. The program is running on Ubuntu, the languange is python by the moment ( C++ later), to the microcontroller is connected by a serial cable, the volume of data is 8 bytes (2 for start and finish of a message, and the others are information), the microcontroller is an Arduino, the messages should be sent in a frequency of 10 [ms] to 1 [s], it doesn't need to be too fast. The argument for using threads (we were thinking), is that the machine can not be "blind" at any instant, because it can damage what is working on (crops in a farm).